# ¿Cómo unir puntos de diferentes variables en una gráfica con ggplot?

Tags: rstudio, unicode, toolbar, ggplot

Tengo la siguiente data y quisiera saber si se puede unir los puntos de diferentes variables como se suele hacer en Excel

| No | TIPO | SECTOR | numero_fincas | Total_Animales | N2O_Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aves | AM | 19 | 182 | 16.2 |
| 2 | Aves | CR | 15 | 228 | 20.3 |
| 3 | Aves | ZL | 39 | 480 | 42.8 |
| 4 | Cuyes | AM | 19 | 139 | 16 |
| 5 | Cuyes | CR | 15 | 124 | 14.2 |
| 6 | Cuyes | ZL | 39 | 337 | 38.7 |
| 7 | Legumbres | AM | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | Legumbres | CR | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | Maiz | CR | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | Maiz | ZL | 15 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | Ovino | AM | 19 | 3 | 1.08 |
| 12 | Ovino | CR | 15 | 22 | 521 |
| 13 | Ovino | ZL | 39 | 52 | 18.7 |
| 14 | Porcino | AM | 19 | 22 | 60.8 |
| 15 | Porcino | CR | 15 | 10 | 1023 |
| 16 | Porcino | ZL | 39 | 21 | 26.4 |
| 17 | Vacuno | AM | 19 | 98 | 549 |
| 18 | Vacuno | CR | 15 | 82 | 460 |
| 19 | Vacuno | ZL | 44 | 277 | 1553 |
| 20 | Verduras | CR | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 21 | Verduras | ZL | 10 | 0 | 0 |

Realicé la siguiente gráfica con doble eje "y" obtuve puntos que deseo unirlos para que mejore la visualización, ¿es posible hacerlo?

```
ggplot(NOa, aes(TIPO, Total_Animales, fill=TIPO))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge())+
  geom_point(aes(y=N2O_Total/5, shape=SECTOR))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~.*5, name="N2O (kg de CO2eq)"))+
  facet_wrap(~SECTOR)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes `geom_line()` para agregar una línea, la única particularidad a tener en cuenta es que como estas trabajando con valores de `x` discretos, es necesario establecer el parámetro `group` para que `ggplot` pueda identificar que puntos se conectan entre sí:

```
geom_line(aes(y=N2O_Total/5, group=SECTOR)) +
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, funcionó de maravilla!!